# Read firefox extension version from the extension code itself

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm developing a firefox extension and I'm looking for a way to access (read) the version of my extension from the extension code itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](http://www.oxymoronical.com/blog/2010/03/How-were-breaking-some-extensions-in-the-near-future) provides the APIs you would need to use to make this work.  Even has sample code!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nsIFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I//O) and read your own .rdf, I suppose.